# Stochastically flipping coins until we see a certain number of heads in two possible durations of time

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Imagine that I'm flipping a biased coin (at a rate given by a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$), where the probability the coin lands heads-up is $p$ (tails $q$).  I keep flipping the coin until I see $M$ coins turn up heads in a window of time of length $t_1$, or $N$ coins turn up heads in a window of time of length $t_2$ (where $t_2 > t_1$ and $N > M$).  For example, if $t_1 = 5$ seconds and $t_2 = 10$ seconds, and if $M = 5$ and $N = 6$, I'll stop if $M = 5$ heads appear in a span of time $<5$ seconds regardless of the total number of coin tosses in this window of time, or if $N = 6$ heads appear in $10$ seconds.  If a time $>t_2$ passes where no coins or tossed, or if all tosses turn up tails, then previous tosses have no bearing on the probability of stopping from this point forward in time --- I'll call this a "Reset Point".

Let $P_1$ be the probability that we stop because $M$ heads appeared in $\leq t_1$ seconds, and let $P_2$ be the probability that we stop because $N$ heads appeared in $t_2$ seconds.  Can we find analytic expressions for $P_1$ and $P_2$?  What probability distribution do we have, starting from an arbitrary "Reset Point", of stopping about some total amount of time $T_g$?

Special note regarding Douglas Zare's comment that we can reformulate the above coin tossing procedure with some new $\lambda_p = p \lambda$, and then simply focus on the number of coin tosses vs. the number of coin tosses as well as the outcome of the toss.  No argument with this here.  However, I'll leave the original posting as is (unless there are complaints) since I am very curious what happens if we treat individual "tails" events for coin tosses as reducing the running count for the number of "heads" events in relevant time intervals (of length $t_1$ and $t_2$, respectively).  However, this added complexity should be ignored if it presents problems for finding an analytic solution to the problem in the original posting.

For the sake of completeness, let $P_1'$, $P_2'$, and $T_g'$ (as otherwise defined above) be the modified probabilities and expected total amount of time if a coin toss with the output of "tails" subtracts $1$ from the number of coin tosses turning up "heads" in any window of time in which the coin was tossed (as described in a bit more detail in the above paragraph).  This is only meant as a supplement to the original posting, and I'll of course consider answers to be complete without this.

Comment: If you are only looking at heads, why not look at the Poisson process of rate $p\lambda$ for heads?

Comment: @DouglasZare Sorry for the delay - you're absolutely right. The actual situation I was working on did involve some extra complexity concerning a run of "tails" events, but I pulled this out of the question at the last minute to make things simpler.  I'll add a note regarding this point to the original posting.